# TFS branching strategy for a patch (bug fix)

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have the following branches in TFS

**Dev**

- 2.3.0-Printing

**Main**

**Rel**

- 2.3.0

***Dev***\2.3.0-Printing was branched off of ***Main*** and after completing and testing was merged back up into Main, which was then branched into ***Rel***\2.3.0.

A bug has been found in *2.3.0* so I'm trying to figure out a branching strategy for *2.3.1* which will include the bug fix.

I was told by a previous co-worker who seemed fluent in TFS to branch from ***Rel***\2.3.0 into **Dev** (ie, don't use the existing/old/previous *2.3.0-Printing* branch), so I'm thinking of calling it ***Dev***\2.3.1-Printing.

**Or, should I first branch *Rel\2.3.0* to *Rel\2.3.1*, then fork a *Dev\2.3.1* branch that can later be merged back into *Rel\2.3.1*, effectively making *Rel\2.3.0* the "Main" of all *2.3* revisions?**

Branching off of **Main** is no longer an option since there have been additional releases since *2.3.0*, which would result in a branch that included these newer changes.

The bug fix needs to make it's way back up into **Main** and I'm thinking it's probably a good idea to avoid circular branch relationships.

Comment: Sounds like branch off of Rel\2.3.1, merge back into main, merge back into whatever dev branches are currently ongoing. Look at "release isolation" in the TFVC branch guidance: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branching-strategies-with-tfvc?view=vsts

Comment: @jessehouwing Branch Rel\2.3.1 off of Rel/2.3.0 directly?

Comment: Depends on whether you need to service 2.3.0 seperately. If this is the new 2.3.0, then just commit to 2.3.0.

Comment: @jessehouwing I need apply a bug fix to 2.3.0 and don't want to modify the release branch, and also need to change the patch version to 1 (2.3.1) correct? If so, I'm thinking of forking Rel\2.3.0 to Rel\2.3.1, then forking Rel\2.3.1 to Dev\2.3.1-bug1, then merging back into Rel and in turn up into Main?

Comment: You could do all of that or none of that. The way you've set it up right now isn't ideal for hotfix and servicing branches, so my recommendation would be to append to 2.3.0 and optionally use labels. You can't go to main from a fork of 2.3.0 without also updating 2.3.0 in your current setup, so you might as well commit directly to 2.3.0.

Comment: What's kissing from your question is what kinds of servicing and hotfixing you envision you need in the future. Keep in mind that TFVC is using heavy branches and strict relations between branches. Every type of servicing you add is going to add a considerable overhead. This ain't git.

Comment: Creating a circular branch relationship is possible but not well supported in the tooling, plus it requires a baseless merge with main. You don't want that unless you love pain.